# REACT_NATIVE_MACOS - Error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER

Tags: react-native, openssl, boringssl

Getting error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER in console log within xcode.

xcode version:Version 10.1 (10B61)

1. npm install react-native-macos-cli -g
2. react-native-macos init MyProject
3. cd MyProject
4. react-native-macos run-macos

   (ie. straight out of the box)
5. Updated the xcode project preferences to include build/ in the location path. This got around code signing issues
6. However while doing the xcode build/run getting the following errors in the xcode console

2019-03-18 18:46:12.558858+1100 MyProject[33041:466498][BoringSSL] boringssl_context_alert_callback_handler(3724) [C1.1:2][0x100c22280] Alert level: fatal, description: protocol version

2019-03-18 18:46:12.558927+1100 MyProject[33041:466498] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_error_print(3676) boringssl ctx 0x60000000a1e0: 4310761320:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/boringssl-109.230.1/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:

2019-03-18 18:46:12.558959+1100 MyProject[33041:466498] [BoringSSL] boringssl_context_get_error_code(3581) [C1.1:2][0x100c22280] SSL_AD_PROTOCOL_VERSION

2019-03-18 18:46:12.562882+1100 MyProject[33041:466498] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x600003709980]: 3:-9836 Err(-9836)